# PrimeFaces calendar does not display calendar when in focus

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

Using JSF2.3 and PrimeFaces 7.0. When my page displays it renders the Textbox portion but when I click on it to put the widget in focus no calendar appears.
Any ideas? I have the xhtml below.

manualsponsorrpt.xhtml

```
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/burnsideweb.css" />
        <title>Manual Sponsor Table Report Generator</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="manrptForm" rendered="#{menubean.sponsorAdminAuthorized}">
                <h:outputText value="Manual Sponsor Table Report Generator" styleClass="title"/>
                <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="true" >
                    <p:autoUpdate />
                </p:messages>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="tableComp" >
                    <p:calendar id="startDate" value="#{sponsorBean.startDate}" />
                    <h:outputText value=" to "/>
                    <p:calendar id="endDate" value="#{sponsorBean.endDate}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Return to Sponsor Table Admin" action="sponsor"
                                       id="return"/>
                    <h:outputText value="  "/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Generate Report" action="#{sponsorBean.runManualReports}"
                                       id="process" />
                </h:panelGrid>
             </h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="You are trying to access one of the LLTS custom apps from outside the Dashboard; this is not permitted. Please log into the dashboard at http://pm.llts.com:9090/LingoApps/faces/menu/menulogon.jsp and access the custom app you want from there."  
                          rendered="#{!(menubean.sponsorAdminAuthorized)}"/></h1>            
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
```

when my

Comment: Any Javascript errors in F12 console?  Your code looks ok to me.

Comment: Haven't coded in a while in PF but maybe you need to add the javascript function on your calendar "onfocus" and tell it to display the calendar? Or in the calendar inputText you gotta check that with F12

Comment: I just created the MVCE and it works fine for me. Can you download this zip: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/files/5361026/pf-cal.zip

Unzip it and run `mvn clean jetty:run` and the navigate to http://localhost:8080/primefaces-test/test.xhtml

Comment: No javascript errors revealed by pressing F12